# How to obtain object id when submitting a form when using Form Model Binding of Laravel

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-form

So this is what I have in my blade file:

```
{!! Form::model($bag, ['action' => 'BagController@crudBag', 'id' => $bag->id]) !!}
```

How do I obtain the `id` in the `BagController@crudBag`?

Comment: What do you get when you add `dd(request()->all());` in `BagController@crudBag`? If your id is not there, check this route in `routes/web.php`

Comment: I do not see the `id` when i added `dd(request()->());`. And, this is what my route looks like: `Route::post('/bag/save/', 'BagController@crudBag');`. Do i have to add a parameter in there?